# Существует ли способ из скрипта на Python понять, что скрипт сейчас будет завершен?

Tags: python

Допустим, мне нужно перед завершением программы сохранить состояние какой-то структуры. Программа завершается недетерминированно. Есть ли какой-либо способ изнутри понять, что программа будет сейчас завершена и выполнить сохранение, или это что-то на грани безумия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html), но вообще, если данные важные, лучше сохранять их заранее.

Comment: Из документации: `Functions thus registered are automatically executed upon __normal__ interpreter termination`

Comment: @MaxU, потому я и уточнил, что важные данные лучше сохранять иначе. При чём-то помимо «normal termination» сохранить данные, полагаю, никак не выйдет.

Comment: `При чём-то помимо «normal termination» сохранить данные, полагаю, никак не выйдет.` - согласен